# C Programming - Size of 2U and 1024U

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, sizeof

I know that the U literal means in c, that the value is a unsigned integer. An unsigned intagers size is 4 bytes.

But how big are 2U or 1024U? Does this simply mean 2 * 4 bytes = 8 bytes for example or does this notation means that 2 (or 1024) are unsigned integers?

My goal would be to figured out how much memory will be allocated if i call malloc like this

```
int *allocated_mem = malloc(2U * 1024U);
```

and prove in a short program my answer what i tried like this

```
printf("Size of 2U: %ld\n", sizeof(2U));
printf("Size of 1024U: %ld\n", sizeof(1024U));
```

I would have expeted for the first line a size of 2 * 4 Bytes = 8 and for the second like 1024 * 4 Bytes = 4096 but the output is always "4".

Would realy appreciate what 2U and 1024U means exactly and how can i check their size in C?

Comment: _An unsigned integers size is 4 bytes_: this is not generally true. It is probably true on _your_ platform.

Comment: `malloc(2U * 1024U)` will allocated 2*1024 (2048 bytes). The `U` suffix means "unsigned", it's rarely used.

Comment: What you want to test is `sizeof(2U * 1024U)`.

Comment: This looks a bit like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: With sizeof(2U * 1024U) i tried to figure out how many bytes would be allocated... i know thats not the correct way to do this but i have no other idea...

Comment: You're confusing a value (like 2 or 1024) with the amount of bytes needed to store it (which depends only on the type).

Comment: @RobertKorber How many bytes would be allocated is determined by the result of the calculation: 2048.

Comment: What problem are you _actually_ trying to solve? Click on the link in the 4th comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My goal would be to figured out how much memory will be allocated if i call malloc like this `int *allocated_mem = malloc(2U * 1024U);`

What is difficult about 2 * 1024 == 2048?   The fact that they are unsigned literals does not change their value.

---

> An unsigned intagers size is 4 bytes. *(sic)*

You are correct.  So `2U` takes up 4-bytes, and `1024U` takes up 4-bytes, because they are both unsigned integers.

---

> I would have expeted for the first line a size of 2 * 4 Bytes = 8 and for the second like 1024 * 4 Bytes = 4096 but the output is always "4".

Why would the value change the size?  The size depends ***only*** on the type.  `2U` is of type `unsigned int`, so it takes up 4-bytes; same as `50U`, same as `1024U`.  They all take **4-bytes**.

You are trying to multiply the value (2) times the size of the type.  That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

> How big?

`2U` and `1024U` are the same size, the size of an `unsigned`, commonly 32-bits or 4 "bytes".  The size of a type is the same throughout a given platform - it does not change because of *value*.

"I know that the U literal means in c, that the value is a unsigned integer." --> OK, close enough so far.

"An unsigned integers size is 4 bytes.".  Reasonable guess yet C requires that `unsigned` are at least 16-bits.  Further, the `U` makes the constant *unsigned*, yet that could be `unsigned`, `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long`, depending on the *value* and platform.

Detail: in C, `2U` is not a *literal*, but a *constant*.  C has *string literals* and *compound literals*.  The literals can have their address taken, but `&2U` is not valid C.  Other languages call `2U` a *literal*, and have their rules on how it can be used.

> My goal would be to figured out how much memory will be allocated if i call malloc like this `int *allocated_mem = malloc(2U * 1024U);`

Instead, better to use `size_t`  for sizing than `unsigned` and check the allocation.

```
size_t sz = 2U * 1024U;
int *allocated_mem = malloc(sz);
if (allocated_mem == NULL) allocated_mem = 0; 
printf("Allocation size %zu\n", allocated_mem);
```

(Aside) Be careful with *computed* sizes.  Do your size math using `size_t` types.  `4U * 1024U * 1024U * 1024U` could overflow `unsigned` math, yet may compute as desired with `size_t`.

```
size_t sz = (size_t)4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

---

The following attempts to print the *size* of the constants which is likely 32-bits or 4 "bytes" and not their *values*.

```
printf("Size of 1024U: %ld\n", sizeof(1024U));
printf("Size of 1024U: %ld\n", sizeof(2U));
```